# Meteor + youtube-iframe-api not working on iOS

Tags: ios, meteor, ios-simulator, youtube-iframe-api

I recently started to build an app with Meteor where I wanted to embed a youtube video. I came across this package on atmospherejs: https://atmospherejs.com/adrianliaw/youtube-iframe-api

When I run the `meteor` command everything works, the app starts and the video shows on the web app, but when I run `meteor run ios` the xcode simulator starts, but the youtube video is nowhere to be seen.

Here is the js code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

// YouTube API will call onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() when API ready.
// Make sure it's a global variable.
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {

    // New Video Player, the first argument is the id of the div.
    // Make sure it's a global variable.

    player = new YT.Player("player", {

        height: "400", 
        width: "600", 

        // videoId is the "v" in URL (ex: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IAhDGYlpqY)
        videoId: "1IAhDGYlpqY", 

        // Events like ready, state change, 
        events: {

            onReady: function (event) {

                // Play video when player ready.
                event.target.playVideo();
            }

        }

    });

};

YT.load();
```

}

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>arc</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to ARC.tv!</h1>

  {{>hello}}

  <div id="player"></div>

</body>

<template name="hello">
  <p>This is the ARC.tv mobile app :D</p>
</template>
```